# Haskell generic Data type

Tags: haskell

Given a list of items Elem defined as follows:

```
date El = Star | War
```

Implement in Haskell the following functions:

```
countWar :: [Elem] -> Int
```

counts the number of elements "War" on the list passed as parameter

This is the first exercise in Haskell, can anyone help me? 
I can not understand what is Star and War ...

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I would recommend start reading a good Haskell tutorial.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to know what is Star or War. You just know that an Elem (btw, you got an error in your code, it should be: `data Elem = …`) is either a Star or a War.

Comment: Your `El` / `Elem` type isn't generic.  It's an [algebraic data type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pattern matching to count the War data while defining a function

```
data Elem = Star | War

countWar:: [Elem] -> Int
countWar [] = 0
countWar (War:xs) = 1 + countWar xs
countWar (_:xs) = countWar xs
```

Answer (score 3):

`Star` and `War` are constructors of the type `E1`, although you later call it `Elem`.  Constructors are like special functions that take zero or more existing values and use them to construct values of a new type.  The usual way to work with constructors like this is through pattern matching:

```
data Elem = Star | War

isStar :: Elem -> Bool
isStar Star = True
isStar War  = False

isWar :: Elem -> Bool
isWar War = True
isWar Star = False
```

Lists can be pattern matched on too

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum [] = 0                -- The sum of an empty list is 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs   -- The sum of a non-empty list is the first 
                          -- element plus the sum of the rest of the list
```

Whenever you see something like `[1, 2, 3]`, this is actually converted into `1:2:3:[]`, since `[]` is defined (effectively) as

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

The `[1, 2, 3]` syntax is just sugar provided by the compiler to make it easier to work with list literals, but the compiler really just sees it in terms of the empty list `[]` and `:`, which we call "cons".

Does this give you some ideas on how to implement `countWar`?